# Diferença entre promise e callback

Tags: javascript, promises

Gostaria de entender um pouco melhor as vantagens de se usar Promise!

hoje utilizo função de callback. Ex:

```
function a(callback) {
   $.ajax({
   ...
   })
   .done(function(data){
      callback(data)
   })
   .fail(function(data){
      callback(data)
   });
}

function b() {
   a(function(response){
     console.log(response)
   });
}
```

Já com Promise, ficaria algo assim:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  $.ajax({
   ...
   })
   .done(function(data){
      resolve(data)
   })
   .fail(function(data){
      reject(data)
   });
});

promise.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Eu gostaria de saber se funcionalmente existem diferenças nos dois modelos?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> [...] existem [funcionalmente] diferenças nos dois modelos[?]

Fundamentalmente não. *Promises* são, no fundo, *callbacks*; funcionalmente a diferença é que o modelo de *promises* provê uma maneira padrão de gerência de retorno de valores e excessões, assim como um controle de fluxo via *handlers*.

A grande vantagem de implementação de *promises* é que o retorno da declaração é uma variável, o que torna o processo de encadeamento de handlers muito mais simples - permitindo, por exemplo, avaliações em cascata.

Um post (em inglês) que elabora este assunto mais a fundo [pode ser encontrado em SoftwareEngineering.StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/302455/is-there-really-a-fundamental-difference-between-callbacks-and-promises).

Answer (score 10):

Promise representa uma promessa de um resultado futuro de uma operação assíncrona. E Promises podem ser entendidos como callbacks assíncronos.

Uma das vantagens que conheço é ao usar [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Retorna uma promise que resolve quando todas as promises no argumento iterável forem resolvidas.

```
Promise.all([chamada1(), chamada2(), ...]).then(function(resultado) {
    //Resultado é um array contém os valores das três promises
}).catch(function(error) {
    //Se ao menos uma promise for rejeitada
});
```

Ou seja, é possível fazer *n* chamadas assíncronas e efetuar alguma operação após todas serem concluídas.

Em [inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks) uma discussão onde explicaram mais vantagens e características.

Answer (score 3):

Uma promise é exatamente o que o nome diz, uma promessa. Sua função "promete" que vai retornar algo, esse algo pode ser um sucesso, erro, mensagem e etc.

O que você vai fazer com o que foi retornado do `promise` é um `callback`. Ou seja, uma `promise` retorna um dado e o `callback` trata esse dado.

O método `Ajax` do `jQuery` que você deu como exemplo é um exemplo de `promise`.

```
// função principal que retorna a promise
var ajax = $.ajax('url');

// promise retornou sucesso (resolve) então podemos tratar os dados
ajax.done(function( data ) {
    // do something awesome
})

// promise retornou erro (reject) então precisamos tratar o erro
ajax.fail(function( error ){
    // something went wrong
});
```

No exemplo que você deu não é necessário encapsular o `Ajax` numa `promise` porque o `Ajax` em si já é uma `promise`.

Veja outro exemplo de `promise`

```
var preload = function( url ) {
    return new Promise(function( resolve, reject ) {
        var image = new Image();

        image.onload  = function() {
            resolve( image );
        };

        image.onerror = function() {
            reject( Error('Error while loading image: ' + url)) ;
        };

        image.src = url;
    });
};
```

E para usar

```
var preloadImage = preload('image-path');

preloadImage.then(function() {
    // imagem carregou
});

preloadImage.catch(function() {
    // deu erro no carregamento
});
```

`.then()` e `.catch()` são os callbacks da promise `preload`

Agora veja o mesmo exemplo anterior, porém agora com `callback`.

```
var preload = function( url, success, error ) {
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload  = function() {
        success( image );
    };

    image.onerror = function() {
        error( Error('Error while loading image: ' + url)) ;
    };

    image.src = url;
};
```

E para usar os `callbacks` seria algo assim

```
preload('image-path', function( image ) {
    // sucesso ao carregar a imagem
}, function( error ) {
    // deu erro ao carregar a imagem
});
```

Comment: Boa cara! Valeu pela dica de não usar callback ou promise no ajax. Não havia notado que era só dar um return $.ajax na minha function a e usar a.done(function(){}).fail(function(){}) na function b. ;)