# Qual usar no Ajax, success ou done?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Às vezes eu vejo utilizarem `success`, às vezes eu vejo `.done`, para tratar a resposta obtida na requisição.

- Qual eu devo usar?
- Existe alguma diferença entre as duas? Qual?

A mesma coisa para `.error` e `.fail`.

Utilizo o jQuery 3.2.1.

Comment: O `.done` sempre é executado, enquanto que `.success` só é chamado caso ocorra sucesso. Não sei a distinção entre `.fail` e `.error`

Comment: Deve ser a mesma coisa

Comment: Não são. Os métodos `done` e `fail` estão relacionados ao retorno da função `$.ajax`, que é um Promise. Os métodos `success` e `error` são *callbacks* executados dentro da própria função.

Answer (score 28):

Conceitualmente eles não são a mesma coisa, mas o resultado produzido é exatamente o mesmo. As funções `success` e `error` são denominadas *callbacks*. Por sua vez, as funções `done` e `fail` são métodos de um *Promise*.

[Diferença entre promise e callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168824/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-promise-e-callback)

O resultado é exatamente o mesmo porque o jQuery utiliza os próprios métodos `done` e `fail` para executar as funções `success` e `error`. Veja o trecho de código retirado do [repositório oficial](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js) (linha 662):

```
// Install callbacks on deferreds
completeDeferred.add( s.complete );
jqXHR.done( s.success );
jqXHR.fail( s.error );
```

Neste caso, `s.success` faz referência ao `success` passado em `options`, assim como `s.error` faz referência a `error`.

**Qual deles utilizar?**

Se você possui apenas uma função `success` e `error`, não faz diferença. Use qual preferir. Utilizar o `done` e `fail` são úteis quando você precisa executar múltiplas funções em cada evento:

```
$.ajax("dominio.com")
    .done(fazAlgo1)
    .done(fazAlgo2)
    .fail(deuErrado1)
    .fail(deuErrado2);
```

Utilizando `success` e `error` você não consegue atribuir várias *callbacks*. Existem ainda a *callback* `complete` que é executada sempre, após a execução de `success` ou `error`. Neste caso, o método semelhante no *Promise* seria o `always`.

Para mais informações, vale ler a documentação oficial citada na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217984/5878)

> **Nota:** é importante salientar que os métodos `.success` e `.error` que a documentação cita como obsoletos não são as *callbacks* `success` e `error`. São, na verdade, métodos presentes no *Promise* em versões antigas do jQuery. **As funções *callbacks* ainda podem ser utilizadas**.

**Exemplo utilizando *callbacks***:

Utilizando a função *callback* `success`.

```js
$(() => {

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
    method: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: users => {
      $(users).each(i => {
        console.log(users[i].name);
      });
    },
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Exemplo utilizando *Promise***

Utilizando o método `done` do objeto *Promise* retornado por `$.ajax`.

```js
$(() => {

  const request = $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
    method: "get",
    dataType: "json"
  });
  
  request.done(users => {
    $(users).each(i => {
      console.log(users[i].name);
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Exemplo utilizando métodos obsoletos do *Promise* (OBSOLETO)**

Utilizando o método `success` do objeto *Promise* retornado por `$.ajax`.

> Este método está presente apenas para referência, mas o mesmo está obsoleto desde a versão 1.8 do jQuery e foi removida completamente no jQuery 3. **Não utilize-a**.

```js
$(() => {

  const request = $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
    method: "get",
    dataType: "json"
  });
  
  request.success(users => {
    $(users).each(i => {
      console.log(users[i].name);
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Exemplo utilizando *fetch***

Uma alternativa está em testes no momento chamada [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). A função é basicamente o que `$.ajax` faz, acredito eu, mas será nativa no navegador, não precisando importar uma biblioteca de terceiros. Uma requisição GET, por exemplo, poderia ser feita assim:

```js
const request = new Request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", {"method": "GET"});

fetch(request).then(response => {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json().then(data => {
      data.forEach(user => {
        console.log(user.name);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Ao meu ver ela será muito melhor de utilizar, não apenas por ser nativa, mas por ser semântica, trabalhando com objetos do tipo `Request`, `Response`, `Headers`, etc. Mas lembrando, ainda está em fase de testes.

---

**Outras leituras**

[O que são promises (promessas) em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119907/5878)

[Como realmente aprender a usar promessas em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16921/5878)

[O que é callback?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/5878)

[Qual a diferença entre function() {} e () => {}? Por que não funciona o $http.get?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143399/5878)

Comment: UHMMM agora eu entendi a diferença bem legal

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a documentação do [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), segue abaixo os status

> **jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ){});**
>   Uma alternativa para a opção de retorno de *success*.
>
> ---
>
> **jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){});**
>   Uma alternativa para o retorno de erro, o método .fail() substituiu o método .error() que hoje é obsoleto.
>
> ---
>
> **jqXHR.always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown){}); (adicionado em jQuery 1.6)**
>   Uma alternativa para a opção de chamada quando a requisição está completa. O método .always() substituiu o método .complete() que hoje está obsoleto.
>
> Caso seja uma solicitação bem-sucedida, os argumentos da função são os mesmos de .done(). Para solicitações que ocorreram erros, os argumentos são iguais aos de .fail().
>
> ---
>
> **jqXHR.then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {}, function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){});**
>   Incorpora a funcionalidade dos métodos .done() e .fail(), permitindo (a partir de jQuery 1.8) trabalhar com Promise.
>
> ---
>
> **Importante**: os retornos de jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error() e jqXHR.complete() foram removidos a partir da versão 3.0 do jQuery. Você pode usar jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail() e jqXHR.always() como alternativa.