# Salvar objeto retornado pelo metodo get

Tags: javascript, ajax

Como posso retornar pra uma variável o objeto resultado de uma requisição `get`?

Estou tentando fazer assim e não funciona:

```
var x = $.get("https://api-nave-twitter.herokuapp.com/tweets", function(data){
    event.preventDefault();
    var tam = data.length;
    printTweet(data,tam);
    return data;
});
```

Comment: Dê uma lina nesta pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/5878

Comment: retorn um objeto com varias campos sobre a resposta, percebi que o que quero fica no x como responseJSON, para obter o só esse array é só atribuir x.responseJSON a uma variavel?

Comment: Felipe, o que está fazendo é uma chamada assíncrona, então o JS não sabe quando a requisição será completada e, desta forma, não sabe o valor que deveria ser retornado para `x`. O que é retornado, de fato, é uma promessa (do inglês, *Promise*) que pode ser utilizado para tratar a resposta, porém você já faz isso na sua função anônima. Ao invés de retornar o valor para a variável, implemente a lógica dentro da sua função anônima, utilizando os dados em `data`. Se não entendeu algo que falei, sugiro nomavente a leitura que citei antes.

Comment: entendi sim, é que eu precisava reutilizar o objeto depois em outra função, e meu pensamento era fazer a requisição somente uma vez. Eu faço o get, pego uma lista e imprimo na tela imediatamente. Se o usuario clicar em um botão ele usa essa mesma lista, ordena ela e reimprime só que ordenada na tela. É melhor fazer a requisição duas vezes?

Comment: Felipe, se precisar chamar outra função chame, mas faça isso de dentro do callback (do que você já tem ou do .done da promessa). Só não recomendaria guardar o valor numa variável do escopo externo.

Comment: Poderia dizer o que não funciona?

Comment: @FelipeAdamoli Você pode a requisição apenas se o valor não for, digamos, `null`.

Answer (score 1):

O retorno da função `$.get` é uma promessa, então você pode utilizar o método `done` sempre que desejar utilizar o retorno obtido. Por exemplo, abaixo fiz que logo que a página carregue a lista de *tweets* seja exibida na tela utilizando o método `done`. Neste caso, ele é equivalente ao utilizar a função anônima como *callback*.

Você pode ler mais aqui: [Qual usar no Ajax, success ou done?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217973/5878)

O interesse é que quando pressionado o botão, os mesmos *tweets* sejam listados de forma ordenada. Para simplificar, fiz a ordenação pelo valor do `id` retornado pelo servidor. Perceba que no tratamento do evento `click` utilizei novamente o método `done` da promessa. Esse método funciona assim: dada um evento assíncrono, nesse caso a requisição, o método `done` invoca a função *callback* passada a ele quando o evento ser finalizado; caso seja passado uma nova função *callback* após o evento estiver finalizado, a função é prontamente executada. Neste exemplo, para listar os *tweets*, a função esperará a requisição ser completada e, quando pressionar o botão, a ordenação será executada imediatamente, pois a requisição já teria finalizada.

Na verdade, mesmo que a requisição ainda não tenha sido finalizada quando pressionar o botão o funcionamento seria o mesmo, pois as funções *callback*, tanto de listar como de ordenar, seriam invocadas nesta ordem, gerando o mesmo resultado.

```js
$(() => {
  const ul = $("ul");
  const button = $("button");
  const tweets = $.get("https://api-nave-twitter.herokuapp.com/tweets");
  
  tweets.done(function (data) {
    $(data).each(function (index, tweet) {
      ul.append($("<li>").text(tweet.text));
    });
  });
  
  button.on("click", function (event) {
    tweets.done(function (data) {
      let sorted = data.sort((a, b) => a.id <= b.id);
      
      ul.empty();
      
      $(data).each(function (index, tweet) {
        ul.append($("<li>").text(tweet.text));
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
<button>Ordenar por id</button>
```