# Receber resultado de um ajax como retorno

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dentro do seguinte cenário:

```
funcao1 = function() {
    $.ajax({
        success: function(data) {
                     return data;
                 }
    });   
}

funcao2 = function() {
    var dados = funcao1();
}
```

É possível eu receber, mesmo que seja através de promises, o resultado do ajax da `funcao1` na `funcao2`?

Comment: Veja na documentação o que a função `$.ajax` retorna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar async/await? Se puder, fica simples, veja:

```
var funcao1 = async function() {
        var result
    var ajax = await $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.nulbox.com',
        success: function(data) {
          result = data
        }
    });
    return result
}

var funcao2 = async function() {
    var dados = await funcao1();

    console.log(dados)
}

funcao2()
```

> Veja o exemplo funcionando 
>   [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/adrianprado/3Lxodmzy/).

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo utilizar a solução do `Adrian`, por utilizar a API mais nova, do ES7, com `async/await`.

Mas você também pode fazer criando uma `Promise` estilo ES6, veja como ficaria:

```js
funcao1 = function () {
    return new Promise((result, failure) => {
        $.ajax("https://api.nulbox.com", {
            success: function (data) {
                result(data);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                failure(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
funcao2 = function () {
    funcao1()
        .then(d => console.log(d))
        .catch (e => console.error(e));
}
funcao2();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

A função [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) possui como retorno um objeto [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) que possui um método `done`. Ou seja, basta retornar esse objeto e utilizar o método quando precisar da resposta da requisição.

```js
const request = function () {
  return $.ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
}

const response = request();

response.done(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Leitura complementar:

- [Qual usar no Ajax, success ou done?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217973/5878)