# Como mostrar a mensagem de erro da validação de um dado na tela com append?

Tags: php, javascript, append

Estou tentando esboçar como na imagem abaixo os erros cometidos por inserção errônea de dados no formulário. Porém, só funciona quando os dados são inseridos corretamente.

[image: A mensagem quando se insere corretamente os dados é "Dados inseridos corretamente"]

O código javascript é

```
$("#formCadastro").on("submit", function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var dados = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: getRoot() + 'controllers/controllerCadastro',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: dados,
    success: function (xhr) {
        $(".retornoCad").empty();
        $(".retornoCad").append("Dados inseridos com sucesso!");
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        $(".retornoCad").empty();
        getCaptcha();
        $.each(xhr.response, function(key,value){
            $(".retornoCad").append(value + '<br>');
        });
        
    }
});
```

});

E o .php de validação é

```
public function validateFinalCad($arrVar)
    {
        if (count($this->getErro()) > 0) {
        
            $arrResponse = [
                // print_r($this->getErro())
                "retorno" => "erro",
                "erros" => print_r($this->getErro())
            ];
        } else {
           $arrResponse = [
                // print_r($this->getErro())
                "retorno" => "success",
                "erros" => null
            ];
            /*$this->cadastro->insertCad($arrVar);*/
        }
        return json_encode($arrResponse);
    }
```

Comment: Caso a resposta da validação retorne um status de resposta HTTP  4**, 5** (exemplo 422,500) aí sim você consegue validar utlizando error : . Veja nas ferramentas do desenvolvedor > network > XHR a resposta e o código. Verifique também no success e error utilizando console.log(xhr) para debugar as mensagens etc.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: irei reeditar. Mas o problema é simples, por isso não escrevi tanto.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Desconsiderando outras possíveis falhas, creio que o problema está na função **print_r**.

Conforme a documentação, ela imprime o conteúdo da variável de maneira "legível para humanos". Mas no seu caso, você quer que ela retorne seu conteúdo. Portanto, deve passar o segundo parâmetro para indicar isso, através de um valor que seja avaliado como **TRUE**.

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print-r.php

```php
public function validateFinalCad($arrVar)
    {
        if (count($this->getErro()) > 0) {
        
            $arrResponse = [
                // print_r($this->getErro())
                "retorno" => "erro",
                // "erros" => print_r($this->getErro()) o erro está aqui
                "erros" => print_r($this->getErro(), true) // irá retornar o conteúdo de '$this->getErro()' e não escrevêlos (que é o que ela faz por default)
            ];
        } else {
           $arrResponse = [
                // print_r($this->getErro())
                "retorno" => "success",
                "erros" => null
            ];
            /*$this->cadastro->insertCad($arrVar);*/
        }
        return json_encode($arrResponse);
    }


  [1]: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print-r.php
```

Comment: utilizei a alteração indicada. No entanto, ao colocar "true", ele exibe a mensagem "Dados inseridos corretamente", não o erro referente a não validação do dado inserido incorretamente.

Comment: Nese caso, você deve verificar o método getErro(), pois ele que está retornando esse texto. O trua acrescentado faz com que a mensagem que seria enviada para o fluxo HTML seja retornada pela função. Em nenhum momento o conteúdo é alterado.

Answer (score 1):

Vou deixar um pequeno source para estudo e melhor entendimento quanto a requisção ajax utilizando jquery.
Para esse post utilizei essa api fake para testes https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

Veja os logs no console do navegador.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // ID = 1 EXISTENTE
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (xhr) {
            //OBVIAMENTE
            console.log('SUCESSO: ', xhr);
        }
    });


    // ID = -1 INEXISTENTE (error)
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/-1',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (xhr) {
            console.log('SUCESSO: ', xhr);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            //status > 400 aqui
            console.log('ERRO: ', xhr);
            console.log('STATUS CODE: ', xhr.status);
            console.log('STATUS TEXT: ', xhr.statusText);
            console.log('RESPONSE JSON: ', xhr.responseJSON);
            console.log('RESPONSE JSON: ', xhr.responseText);
        }
    });

    // ID = -1  INEXISTENTE (utilizando fail)
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/-1',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (xhr) {
            console.log('SUCESSO: ', xhr);
        }
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
        //status > 400 aqui
        console.log('ERRO USANDO FAIL');
        console.log('ERRO: ', xhr);
        console.log('STATUS CODE: ', xhr.status);
        console.log('STATUS TEXT: ', xhr.statusText);
        console.log('RESPONSE JSON: ', xhr.responseJSON);
        console.log('RESPONSE JSON: ', xhr.responseText);
    });
</script>
```

Complemente o post com a leitura desse post [Qual usar no Ajax, success ou done?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217973/qual-usar-no-ajax-success-ou-done)

Comment: Ao negativar comente o motivo para que eu possa melhorar nos próximos posts. :)